# Problems with constructor in Android

Tags: java, android

I have this code the final objective is to sort multiple arrays.
The problem it's when i try to access ".color" on my color Comparator.

**My constructor:**

```
import java.util.*;
    public class ColorClothes {

        public ColorClothes() // <------ method
        {

        }

        public Clothes[] Initialize(Clothes[] item) {
            Clothes firstry[] = new Clothes[4]; 


            System.out.println("Unsorted");

            for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
            }

            System.out.println("\nSorted By Color\n");

            Arrays.sort(item, new ColorComparator());

            for (int i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(item[i].record + "     " + item[i].color + "     " + item[i].clothes);
            }

            return item;
        }


        public class Clothes {
            public int record;
            public String color;
            public String clothes;
        }
    }
```

**My ColorComparator:**

```
import java.util.Comparator;

class ColorComparator implements Comparator
{
    public int compare(Object str1, Object str2)
    {
        String str1Color = ((ColorClothes)str1).color;
        String str2Color = ((ColorClothes)str2).color;

        return str1Color.compareTo(str2Color);
    }
}
```

Cannot resolve "color" this happens on my ColorComparator. What i am doing wrong?

Comment: `ColorClothes` does not have the field `color`, but the class `Clothes`.

Comment: An instance of `ColorClothes` doesn't have a color. It sounds like you should be accepting an instance of `Clothes` instead. I'd strongly recommend that if you're new to Java, you avoid using nested types, as they'll confuse you. I'd also suggest you learn about generics so that you can implement `Comparator<Clothes>` and avoid public fields.

Comment: Problem solved ty for help me to understand my error :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your color attribute is in the Class `Clothes` but you are casting into `ColorClothes` there `((ColorClothes)str1).color`

Try :

```
((Clothes)str1).color
```

ps : public attribute in class is not really Object Oriented programming

Answer (score 0):

Cloths is not getting resolved. 
Try this:

```
String str1Color = ((ColorClothes.Clothes)str1).color;

String str2Color = ((ColorClothes.Clothes)str2).color;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".